# Use STL Containers with Struct

Tags: c++, struct, stl, iterator

I want to store the address of each of the items of my linked list represented by this struct:

```
struct Node
   {
       int data;
       Node* next;
   };
```

I made an unordered set for this as:

```
unordered_set<Node*> h;
```

I defined the iterator as

```
unordered_set <Node*>::iterator got = h.find (&headB);
```

This naturally threw a lot of compiler errors. Reading up on forums, I realized that this was wrong because since Node isnt a standard data type, this iterator wouldnt work. Reading up more, I also saw somewhere that I also needed to define an operator for this implementation. I searched a lot on Stack Overflow but didnt find anything that answers this question.

So basically, I just want to know how do we make struct's work with any STL containers and iterators: How do we define containers and implement algorithms ( insert, search, deletion on them)

Comment: Why would this not work, the little amount of code looks fine. Can you provide the real code?

Comment: Compiles fine, after adding the boilerplate: https://ideone.com/NpW6zj

Comment: Here is the complete code: https://ideone.com/tBpSBF

Comment: Why are you doing ```h.insert(&headA);``` shouldn't it be ```h.insert(headA);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting and finding incorrectly.
Your elements are of type `Node*`.

You have an "address of" operator (`&`) before Your elements. Which means You are trying to add a `Node**`, which is the incorrect type.
So the compiler is saying:

```
prog.cpp:67:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_set<Node*>::insert(Node**)’
```

The correct way is to add an element of the correct type, which is `Node*`, by removing the address of operator (`&`);

Unless You wanted the address of a pointer, then You need the container to store `Node**`

Comment: I want to save the address. I'm not sure why we would need double pointers (**). A line on that would be greatly helpful.

I did try your suggestion and its stuck on a particular line (Marked in comment). Please see: https://ideone.com/P5AZR7

Comment: Double pointers are needed because of the refrence of a pointer. Why are You using a refrence?

Comment: Actually in this case the ampersand means ```address_of```. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/address-of-operator-amp

Comment: My understanding was that a single pointer is sufficient to store the address of a variable. Is that wrong?
The question is to detect the meeting points of two linked lists. My strategy is to make a hash of the addresses of each node in one linked list and then see which address of the other node exists in the hash ( as that is the common node, hence the meeting point). Since I am comparing addresses, hence the reference/ address operator (&) is needed.

Comment: But You already have an address ```headA``` and ```headB``` is of type ```Node*``` so You don't have to take it's address.

Comment: A variable of type ```Node*``` is already storing an address. So You just use the variable.

Comment: Remove the address of operator (```&```), revert the types to ```Node*```. The problem is in the HeadB loop. The next element is never assigned to HeadB. The while loops have the incorrect condition. It should be ```while (headA)``` or ```headB```.